# request_denied when i include key=my_api_key

Tags: google-maps-api-3

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

That url will work. However, if i include my key:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false&key=abc123

I get request denied (i replace abc123 with my actual key). I just requested the key a few hours ago. I also turned on the maps api v2 and v3 for my domain. Even with both on i still get request_denied. Does anyone know why it doesn't accept my api key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geocoding-API doesn't require a key. Use the key only where it's needed/available(for the services listed in the [API-console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/))

Comment: All Maps API applications* should load the Maps API using an API key see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Comment: You are not loading the maps-API, you are requesting the geocoding-service, which is not listed inside the API-console.

Comment: damn. I was hoping i'd get the extra requests by using the api key since it says you get 25,000/day instead of 2500

Comment: @Dr.Molle, it does not require key, but does it have limit?

Comment: 1. there are changes(this question is 4 years old), a key now may be used for the geocoding-API(fortunately). 2. the usage of a key doesn't affect the [limits for the geocoding-API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits) , but it will change the target of the limits. Without a key the limits are related to the IP-address(of the server which sends the request). When you use the key it's related to your project. So when you don't use a key you will share the quota with any application on any domain which will use the same IP(it may be houndreds)

Answer (score 0):

API V3

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&  sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
```

API V2 deprecated

Comment: So this is just if i want to render a map on the page, correct? I'm just looking up lat/long coordinates from an address.

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is that any request with the key needs to be over HTTPS. Trying changing to https://... and it should work.