# Google Places REQUEST_DENIED INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: google-places-api

## Autocomplete

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?input=wash&sensor=true&key=my_key
-> REQUEST_DENIED
```

Wait some seconds:

```
-> INVALID_REQUEST
```

Then waiting and without waiting:

```
-> INVALID_REQUEST
-> INVALID_REQUEST
```

## Another test

Click try out from API console:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.88471,151.218237&radius=100&sensor=true&key=my_key
-> good response
```

Without waiting some seconds same request:

```
-> REQUEST_DENIED
```

Wait some seconds, same request:

```
-> good response
```

Is there some place in documentation or anywhere I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `&key=mykey` from the request? It looks like your requests are being routed amongst a number of servers which are configured differently; but I don't think simple requests (rather than a GET of the API itself) need the key. [It is the case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847022/request-denied-when-i-include-key-my-api-key) that providing a key where one is positively not wanted will yield `REQUEST_DENIED`.

Comment: Removing key I get `REQUEST_DENIED`

Comment: I think I was looking at the wrong place, this one seems the correct https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete Google Maps JS API V3